# Why is gravitational potential energy negative in this Lagrangian?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, oscillators

The question is given as follows:
[image: the question]

From (6.109) shouldn't the Lagrangian be K(kinetic) - U(potential), but here its K + U? Unless the potential energy is negative, if so I'm struggling to come to terms with it.

Comment: Hint: Does P.E. increase or decrease with $\theta$?

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the image and the accompanying text, it seems that the 0 point of your $y$ axis is chosen to be the lowest point of the "box", as can be seen by $$Y_m=-\ell\cos\theta$$ (which is negative for $-\pi/2\le\theta\le\pi/2$). Then potential energy is$$U=mgY_m=-mg\ell\cos\theta$$ which results in a *positive* sign when subtracting $U$.